# Connection to localhost:3000 refused on Android device

Tags: android, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to connect to the restful web service i created through rails from my android app.

When I try to connect to the REST API deployed on `http://localhost:3000` I get this error:

> Connection to http://localhost:3000 refused.

I am running ubuntu natty narwhal.

Hitting this URL via a browser gets the response properly.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Visiting that url via a browser on the device will not, because the server is not running on the local host, ie the device itself, but instead on a remote machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are testing your app on your device then localhost is the device itself. If you are testing in the emulator then take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias) document

> If you need to refer to your host computer's localhost, such as when you want the emulator client to contact a server running on the same host, use the alias 10.0.2.2 to refer to the host computer's loopback interface. From the emulator's perspective, localhost (127.0.0.1) refers to its own loopback interface.

In your case your app/activity is trying to connect on port 3000 to your device not to your host computer.

Comment: Yes, localhost is always the device or emulator itself.  The emulator has an alias to the development machine's loopback interface, but a usb connected device does not.

Comment: ahh, ok, thanks Chris (so I also learned sth). Then the naive workaround would be to connect to your local pc with its private address in your wlan (if you have one)

Comment: Yes.Got it guys.Thanks a lot.I have changed from local host to 10.0.2.2.

Comment: Yes, but that's only going to work on the emulator.  With a physical device, thomas' idea of using wifi and its address on the private subnet is probably best.