# Android app can't connect to socket.io Golang server

Tags: android, go, sockets

I don't know if I'm missing something, because my `Kotlin` code isn't finding the `Golang` socket server. I did a `netstat -ano` and the port 8000 was being used for TCP already so I think the socket server is running fine. But my android still can't find it. Both the server and the emulator is on the same network. Here's my code:

//server(Golang)

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/polling"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/websocket"
)

server := socketio.NewServer(&engineio.Options{
    Transports: []transport.Transport{
        &polling.Transport{
            CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
        },
        &websocket.Transport{
            CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
        },
    },
})

server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
    s.SetContext("")
    fmt.Println("connected:", s.ID())
    return nil
})

server.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
    fmt.Println("notice:", msg)
    s.Emit("reply", "have "+msg)
})

server.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
    fmt.Println("meet error:", e)
})

server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
    fmt.Println("closed", reason)
})

go server.Serve()
defer server.Close()

http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./asset")))

fmt.Println("ScktSrv Serving at localhost:8000...")
fmt.Print(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
```

//android(Kotlin)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}

try {
    mSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8000/skt")
    Log.d(TAG, "success: ${mSocket.id()}")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.localizedMessage?.let { Log.e(TAG, it) }
}

mSocket.connect()
mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect)
mSocket.on("reply", onReply)

private var onConnect = Emitter.Listener {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnect")
    mSocket.emit("notice", "{\"relay_num\": 4, \"to_status\": 1}")
}

private var onReply = Emitter.Listener {
    Log.i(TAG, "replyMsg: ${it[0]}")
}
```

UPDATE:

Before @dev.bmax's answer, I already found out something about enabling cleartexttraffic and already added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on my `AndroidManifest.xml`, but the app still can't connect to the server. `Socket.connected()` returns false right now.

Also, how should you actually connect to the server? Do I just need `http://10.0.2.2:8000` without any path?

UPDATE:

I just noticed that I keep getting a log that looks like this:

```
tagSocket(6) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

And it keeps popping up on the logcat

UPDATE:

I looked around for other code, and I found a working one. Which fortunately or unfortunately, is quite simple. Here's the codes I found:

//Golang

```
listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8000")
for {
    conn, _ := listener.Accept()
    fmt.Printf("%s --- %s\n", conn.LocalAddr(), conn.RemoteAddr())
    io.WriteString(conn, "welcome to socket")
}
```

//Android Kotlin

```
val host = "192.168.100.250"
val port = 8000

Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
    try {
        val socket = java.net.Socket(host, port)
        receiveMove(socket)
    } catch (e: ConnectException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket ConnExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText(this, "connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket ConnExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering, why does that barebones code work and the one provided by googollee library doesn't? I don't think I missed any settings for both sides.

UPDATE:

Got some progress. Found an `android` code that works, but for some reason is doing some unexpected issue. Here's the details of the change I made on the android side:

// app build.gradle

```
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

// MainActivity.kt

```
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket

init {
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://<local_IP>:8000/socket.io/")
    }catch (e: ConnectException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket ConnExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
    }catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket URISynExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
    }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket Exc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
    }
}
```

// AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
//I used to have android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" here as well
```

With those changes, the app connects to the server now. But immediately after connecting, the app seems to get disconnected. Then it connects to the server again, then gets disconnected again, then connects to the server, and this cycle doesn't seem to stop. I'm getting a `closed client namespace disconnect` on the disconnects.

Comment: Hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180863/connection-to-localhost3000-refused-on-android-device. 
`localhost` refers to the loopback address of the Android device itself. Try with the IP address instead.

Comment: Didn't seem to work, unfortunately

Comment: @rminaj, did you try with server's lan ip address? Also port forwarding the router?
If server is running on Linux, then adding  "mylanip localhost" to /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Go-socket.io uses version 1.4 of Socket.IO, it seems you are importing the client for v2 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the bits to make this work. I think the biggest issue was on the android side. Replacing the library to use seemed to have fixed all the issue, then just a minor change to fix the immediate disconnection issue. Here's the final code and additional details for both side:

// Golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/polling"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/websocket"
)

var allowOriginFunc = func(r *http.Request) bool {
    return true
}

func main() {
    server := socketio.NewServer(&engineio.Options{
        Transports: []transport.Transport{
            &polling.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
            &websocket.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
        },
    })

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        fmt.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        fmt.Println("notice:", msg)
        s.Emit("reply", "have "+msg)
    })

    server.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
        fmt.Println("error:", e)
    })

    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
        fmt.Println("closed", reason)
    })

    go server.Serve()
    defer server.Close()

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./asset")))

    fmt.Println("Socket server serving at localhost:8000...")
    fmt.Print(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

// android kotlin

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

app build.gradle

```
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

// MainActivity.kt or wherever you want to put this

```
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mSocket: Socket
    ...
    
    init {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://<host>:8000/")
        }catch (e: ConnectException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket ConnExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket URISynExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Exc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        mSocket.connect()
        
        binding.btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i(TAG, "isConnected: ${mSocket.connected()}")
            mSocket.emit("notice", "from_app_msg")
        }
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        mSocket.off()
        mSocket.disconnect()
    }
}
```

About the immediate disconnection, it seems like you don't really need to add `/socket.io` when trying to connect on the android side. Removing that fixed the disconnection issue. And you don't need an `asset` folder on your project. Man, this `socket.io` thing is weird.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to identify the problem without seeing the logs, error messages.
One thing that could be the reason (besides an incorrect IP address or port number) is using cleartext connection (HTTP instead of HTTPS). Note that starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

You can try to either use a secure connection (HTTPS) or enable cleartext traffic in the `AndroidManifest` using the `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute. More information can be found in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted).

Comment: On the golang sides, I'm getting a "write: timeout" error on `OnError()` and "client namespace disconnect" on `OnDisconnect()`. But this is just recently, I didn't get anything when I posted this question.

Comment: Are you sure the URL that you connect to us correct? I would expect it to look like "wss://10.0.2.2:8000"

Comment: Not quite sure myself. But that's the sample code from the official documentation of socket.io, so I'm thinking that it should work

Comment: Just tried to `wss://` and I got this error: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: wss`

Answer (score 1):

The `client namespace disconnect` error receiving due to the namespace (url path) `/skt` is not defined in the golang code.

See the sample

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/polling"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/websocket"
)

// Easier to get running with CORS. Thanks for help @Vindexus and @erkie
var allowOriginFunc = func(r *http.Request) bool {
    return true
}

func main() {
    server := socketio.NewServer(&engineio.Options{
        Transports: []transport.Transport{
            &polling.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
            &websocket.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
        },
    })

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        log.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        log.Println("notice:", msg)
        s.Emit("reply", "have "+msg)
    })

    server.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
        log.Println("meet error:", e)
    })

    // I've added a new endpoint skt
    // Comment this block of code and refresh the htmt page
    // and this will show `closed client namespace disconnect`
    {
        server.OnConnect("/skt", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
            s.SetContext("")
            log.Println("connected:", s.ID())
            return nil
        })

        server.OnEvent("/skt", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
            log.Println("notice:", msg)
            s.Emit("reply", "have [SKT]"+msg)
        })
    }

    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
        log.Println("closed", reason)
    })

    go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("socketio listen error: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()
    defer server.Close()

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../asset")))

    log.Println("Serving at localhost:8000...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

and here is a sample socket connection html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io("http://localhost:8000/skt");
    //   var socket = io("http://localhost:8000"); you can try like this as well

      socket.on('reply', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });

      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('notice', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

hope this will helps you to resolve your problem

Comment: But I'm trying to connect with just `/` on the android code right now and my golang code still looks like the code in the question and I'm getting those error, which keeps appearing btw once it starts appearing for some reason.

Comment: You mean tried to connect it with `http://localhost:8000/` and getting the `namespace` error, correct?

Comment: Yep, and 10.0.2.2:8000 and still got those errors

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, you should try connecting to `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/` or using `127.0.0.1` with the Android app, because you are serving in the Go server the `/socket.io` endpoint for SocketIO.

Comment: Is that what the code meant? Well, I just copy-pasted that from googollee's sample code. Will try that tomorrow

Comment: Well, you see you have this code 
`server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        log.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })` 
which expects connection on the root of the socketio server, but you set up later on the Go server to handle that socketIO server on the `/socket.io` endpoint, with : 
`http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)` 

So, the root of your SocketIO server is actually handled in 127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/ (or localhost) in your Go server, so, that's the endpoint you should try in your Android app.

Comment: Man, that was really confusing. So basically the sample code was actually misleading right from the start?

Comment: It seems so. Try out just changing this line `mSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8000/skt")` to `mSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8000/socket.io")` and see if it solves the issue

Comment: Ok, tried every iteration of the url(no port, with port, with /socket.io/) and the app still didn't connect. I used the actual local IP of my PC just to be sure, and still didn't connect

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to access your server using your own client, try accessing it with a CLI tool or browser.

Here's how you could do it using cURL:

```
curl -i -X GET http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

In your case, `http.Fileserver` will result in a `404 - Not Found` or `403 - Permission Denied` in case './asset' directory does not exist within your Go project's root path, or if you don't have read access.

Reference:

1. [`http.Fileserver.ServeHTTP` calls `toHTTPError`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/net/http/fs.go;l=856-858) which [returns non-specific HTTP error message](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/net/http/fs.go;l=683-697).

Comment: That command returned a `Couldn't connect to server` and using `http://localhost:8000` resulted in a `404 page not found`

Comment: @rminaj Are you sure `asset` directory is present in the root path of your project?